# Overriding template file from custom module not working

Tags: magento2, phtml, override-block

i want to override block phtml file for customer address edit, first i created the `customer_account_edit.xml` at `Namespace/Moduke/view/frontend/layout/` :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
      <referenceBlock name="customer_edit">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Namespace_Module::customer_address_edit.phtml</argument>
        </action>
      </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

then i created the phtml file located at  `Namespace/Module/view/frontend/templates/customer_address_edit.phtml`

but it still load the vendor phtml file, not the one i made

Answer (score 2):

You can also used below code

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
    <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Edit" name="customer_edit" template="Namespace_Module::customer_address_edit.phtml" cacheable="false" >
        <container name="form.additional.info" as="form_additional_info"/>
    </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

Comment: it isnot working

Answer (score 0):

Try below code :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <referenceBlock name="customer_edit">
                <action method="setTemplate">
                    <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Namespace_Modulename::address/edit.phtml</argument>
                </action>
            </referenceBlock>
         </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

After that clear the cache by running command **php bin/magento cache:clean**